# get exact offending field: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: debugging, exception, concurrency, ado.net

In an Update command, I get above error.

I have tried to log out everything, but I cannot find the field that is causing the issue. I did compare the "myoriginal" to the value I get from the database via SSMS and it is exactly the same.

How can I find the exact field that causes the concurrency error?

My code for pinpointing the error:

```
public virtual int Update(global::System.Data.DataRow[] dataRows)
{
  try
  {
    return this.Adapter.Update(dataRows);
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    var msg = "my little exception, " + dataRows.Length + " rows attempted to update";
    foreach (var row in dataRows)
    {
      msg += "row has errors: " + row.HasErrors;
      if (row.HasErrors)
      {
        msg += " descr " +  row.RowError + System.Environment.NewLine;
        foreach (var col in row.GetColumnsInError())
          msg += " col " + row.GetColumnError(col.ColumnName);
      }
      {
        msg += "mynewone";
        msg += System.Environment.NewLine;
        var columns = row.Table.Columns;
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in columns)
          msg += col.ColumnName + "->" + row[col.ColumnName];
        msg += System.Environment.NewLine;

        msg += "myoriginal";
        msg += System.Environment.NewLine;

        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in columns)
          msg += col.ColumnName + "->" + row[col.ColumnName, System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original];
        msg += System.Environment.NewLine;

        msg += "theend";
        msg += System.Environment.NewLine;
      }
    }
    throw new System.Exception(msg, ex);
  }
}
```

The first part (row.HasErrors) - I hoped to detail what is in error - does not produce any output.

The lower part I used to comare against the data in the DB, which seems to be exactly as it should be.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your update statement? Or are you calling a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I simply logged all data out. It turns out I had errors in previous logging logic that prevented me from spotting my error.
And then I found an error in a stored procedure that after an update gave back wrong data (typo, missing "," between two return values).

```
msg += "mynewone";
msg += System.Environment.NewLine;
var columns = row.Table.Columns;
foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in columns)
    msg += col.ColumnName + "->" + row[col.ColumnName];
msg += System.Environment.NewLine;

msg += "myoriginal";
msg += System.Environment.NewLine;

try {
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in columns)
        msg += col.ColumnName + "->" + row[col.ColumnName, System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original];
}
catch (System.Exception) {
    // possible that original data does not exist - simply skip this then
}
msg += System.Environment.NewLine;
```